# Changing images for angular UI DatePicker control

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for just  datepicker control.

By default when we mouse hover inside textbox, it shows up 3 images (close button, up down spinner, button)

I want to remove the first 2 images and change the last one to some other image.
I went through jS code but could not find any code for that.

Anyone who has similar requirement or knows about the code, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The date picker has more than 3 buttons. Clear, Today, Close, Forward, Backward. Can you put your line where you define the date picker?

Comment: All images are appearing inside textbox to the right corner. I just want to remove some of them and replace one with my image. Any ideas ?